# Query to check datetime object not returning expected result

Tags: python, django

I have a model

```
class Availability(models.Model):
    arena = models.ForeignKey(Arena, null=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

which stores an availability object for a particular `Arena`. In my views, i'm trying to find out all `Availability objects` for a particular arena that are present for `Today` i.e, from Midnight to Midnight. For that, I've done the following:

```
def get_schedule(request):
    if 'arena' in request.GET:
        arena = Arena.objects.get(id=request.GET['arena'])
        today = datetime.date.today()
        tomorrow = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        available_object = Availability.objects.filter(arena__id=arena.id, start_date__gte=today, end_date__lte=tomorrow)
        obj = []
        for a in available_object:
            print(a)
            obj.append({
                'start_time': a.start_date.strftime('%H:%M'),
                'end_time': a.end_date.strftime('%H:%M')
            })
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(obj), content_type="application/json")
```

In my table, I have the following object created

```
id = 1
start_date = 2015-03-04 06:00:00
end_date = 2015-03-04 09:00:00
arena_id = 2
```

Passing `arena_id` as 2 in the above `available_object` query returns no values. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure that your `today` is actually 2015-03-04? Do you have timezone support enabled?

Comment: @Selcuk `USE_TZ = True` is what enables time support right? I've added that in my settings file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *naive* `today` might be a later date than 2014-03-04 06:00:00 at the time of your test. Try using a timezone-aware date for today and tomorrow:

```
from django.utils import timezone
...
today = timezone.now().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0)
tomorrow = today + timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: I just realized. In Django admin, when I add an object it sets the date and time to Server time and since i'm in India the added times are GMT while I'm 5.5 hours ahead. Is there a fix for that?

Comment: Yeah your method worked. However, it still wont show me the correct date and time unless the Django admin server time is set to my timezone time.

Comment: You can add `TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Calcutta'` to your settings.py for UTC+05:30. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones for the complete list